# Unexpected character encountered while parsing value from steambot

Tags: json, steambot

I have an big issue trying to get the steambot (https://github.com/Jessecar96/SteamBot) working and I can't get around it.

I get this error when the bot "noticed" an trade offer :

[image]

The bot gets the info from check-items.php and crashes after it.

This the code where the bot crashes:

DepositTradeOfferUserHandler.cs Line 167:

```
   JSONClass responseJsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSONClass>(responseString);

        if (responseJsonObj.success == 1)
        {
            //Get data array from json
            var jsonData = responseJsonObj.data;

            if (jsonData.minDeposit == 1)
            {
                doWebWithCatch(10, () => {
                    if (offer.Accept())
                    {
                        Log.Success("Offer accepted from " + userID);
```

I think its because of the `(responseString);` but I dont know what's the reason.

I can't fix it myself please help me.

Comment: instead of screen shot please provide us the log.

Comment: sry here is the log mate : http://pastebin.com/DjPWXukR